# How the :before psuedo element changes into share icon

Tags: html, css

I seen many websites where the content of a before element is given like

twitter.icon:before{
   content : '\f099'
}

and it appears first like a box and then changes into a twitter icon , no background-image or javascript is used , can some one explain how these icons are created , You can see an example on  http://www.freelancerinsights.com/upwork-reject-profile/

In short I want to know  in above site how , the share  icons  are created,
They did not use background-images neither they used images , So how they created these icons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those icons are created with a vector icon font face such as [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/). Visit their site for simple instructions on how to implement FA on your projects.

On the site you linked, inspecting the social icons you mentioned reveals the Font Awesome implementation:

```
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In current scenario most of web developer create font and embedded them in icon. you can check fontawesome for example, how they use
http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Answer (score 0):

They are created by using Font Awesome webfont icons: http://fontawesome.io/

More over, they are created by using a combination of:

1. the web font file (changing an HTML entity of `\f099` into a specific icon, via the font's character set)
2. CSS classes on the HTML elements to let the browser know where to do this and to what icon. `fa` and `fa-twitter` on an `i` element are utilized by the Font Awesome CSS.
3. Utilizing the `::before` pseudo element (done completely via CSS) to display the icon.

Answer (score 0):

These types of icons are generated by Font Awesome, it gives you `scalable vector icons` which scales automatically with respect to font and screen size.

You just need to include necessary font awesome css file then give a class to a element like

`fa fa-twitter` and you will have twitter icon.

for more info refer this link http://fontawesome.io/